# Checking for unsnapped lines in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, snapping, pipe-network

I am trying to find a way to locate any unsnapped pipes/manholes. I noticed that my snapping environment was not set up in ArcMap the first few times I made edits and I want to go back and reverse those mistakes. There are thousands of pipes and manholes so I am sure I am not the only one to have this happen.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the **Feature Vertices to Points** tool on your pipes, using the **Both Ends** (or maybe **Dangle**) option in **Point Type**.

Then do a select by location using the end points on your manhole layer. This will give you all the snapped manholes. Invert your selection and you'll be able to see  the unsnapped locations

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to build a [topology](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/topologies/creating-a-topology.htm) between your pipes and manholes.  Use rule Endpoint Must Be Covered By with your manholes and pipes, with pipe endpoints needing to be covered by manholes.

[Additional Topo Rules](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-topology/geodatabase-topology-rules-and-topology-error-fixes.htm)